# Doorkeeper error help needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, doorkeeper

I am using doorkeeper for OAuth functionality on my ruby on rails application. Also I am using devise for user security management.

Here is my current doorkeeper.rb file:

```
Doorkeeper.configure do
  orm :active_record

  resource_owner_authenticator do
    user_signed_in? || redirect_to(new_user_session_url)
  end

  admin_authenticator do
    user_signed_in? || redirect_to(new_user_session_url)
  end

  enable_application_owner :confirmation => true

  # authorization_code_expires_in 10.minutes

  # access_token_expires_in 2.hours

  # use_refresh_token

  # default_scopes  :public
  # optional_scopes :write, :update

  # client_credentials :from_basic, :from_params

  # access_token_methods :from_bearer_authorization, :from_access_token_param, :from_bearer_param

  # test_redirect_uri 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

  # skip_authorization do |resource_owner, client|
  #   client.superapp? or resource_owner.admin?
  # end

  # realm "Doorkeeper"
end
```

When I access /oauth/applications, I get an error page which says "uninitialized constant Admin", and "config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in '".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. The problem lay in rails server caching the doorkeeper.rb initialiser file and I needed to restart the server after I had edited that file.